# How to execute JavaScript/jQuery on history back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have button which simply doing this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;" class="button">Back</a>
```

How can I execute JavaScript on the destination page without any history plugins?

Let say I am on page `X` then I went to page `Y` with my Back button, after I click on the button Back page `X` getting displayed, how can I execute any JavaScript in that time?

I want to set some styling witch getting lost after history back and also some text values.

Comment: you can do that on historyChange event listener but still i am not clear what u want to do

Answer (score 0):

Ha ve a look at this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

It has an event for history change.

Hope it helps

Comment: the key was **Without any history plugins**

Comment: sorry about that, ignore my response